# Why my AudioSource plays a little piece of music and then turns of?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make game on Unity where you need to shoot targets with the rhytm.

I wanted to make music to start after 2 seconds when scene started, but it plays a little piece and turns of.

```
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour {

public float lookSpeed = 3;
private Vector2 rotation = Vector2.zero;
RaycastHit hit;
int Weapon;
float ShootTimer = 0;
bool isSleeping;
bool isMusicStarted;
AudioSource music;

void Start(){
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    music = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void Update()
{
    rotation.y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    rotation.x += -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    rotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.x, -15f, 15f);
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0,rotation.y) * lookSpeed;
    Camera.main.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation.x * lookSpeed, rotation.y * lookSpeed, 0);
    StartCoroutine("StartingTheMusic"); 
}

IEnumerator StartingTheMusic(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    music.Play();
    isMusicStarted = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You keep starting the coroutine at every frame. Move the StartCoroutine("StartingTheMusic") call at the end of the Start method. That will solve your problem.